# Cómo puedo copiar un fichero pdf en varias carpetas usando PHP

Tags: php, archivo

Estoy desarrollando una web para subir curriculum. La persona selecciona dos check y de esa selección se debe de guardar el pdf en varias carpetas. Por ejemplo selecciona informática y administración, se debe de guardar el mismo pdf en las dos carpetas. Pero solo logro que se guarde en la primera. A la segunda ya no pasa. Mi código es:

```
switch ($seleccion) {
    case 'Comercial':
        move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['documento']['tmp_name'] , $comercial .$_FILES['documento']['name']);
    case 'Dependiente':
        move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['documento']['tmp_name'] , $dependiente .$_FILES['documento']['name']);
     case 'Conductor':
        move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['documento']['tmp_name'] , $conductor .$_FILES['documento']['name']);
     case 'Logistica':
        move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['documento']['tmp_name'] , $logistica .$_FILES['documento']['name']);
     case 'Administracion':
        move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['documento']['tmp_name'] , $administracion .$_FILES['documento']['name']);
     case 'Informatico':
        move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['documento']['tmp_name'] , $informatico .$_FILES['documento']['name']);
     default:
        move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['documento']['tmp_name'] , $otros .$_FILES['documento']['name']);
     break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ya lo he solucionado en vez de usar `move_uploaded_file` he utilizado el método `copy` por ejemplo

```
copy ($_FILES['documento']['tmp_name'] , $comercial .$_FILES['documento']['name']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Una estructura `switch ... case` no es la mejor opción para resolver esto. Usando un array podrías resolverlo de una forma muy simple.

Supongamos que las selecciones vienen así:

```
#$mFolders representa una selección cualquiera en tus checkbox
$mFolders=array('Comercial', 'Conductor');
```

Podrías recorrer `$mFolders` e ir guardando en las carpetas que ya haya:

```
foreach ($mFolders as $folder){
    copy ($_FILES['documento']['tmp_name'] , $folder."/".$_FILES['documento']['name']);
}
```

Este código te guardará un archivo en cada ruta de `$folder`.

Si en el array de selecciones viniera la información de otra forma, podrías definir `$mFolders` como un array asociativo donde relaciones cada valor con el nombre real de la carpeta en tu servidor.

Comment: Si tienes dos carpetas, en la primera iteración del ciclo se moverá el archivo temporal, para la segunda (y posteriores), fallará, porque ese archivo temporal no existe, ya fue movido.

Comment: Cierto @Triby, gracias por advertirlo. Sería cuestión de cambiarlo por `copy`